# Selenium - System.ArgumentNullException: text cannot be null Parameter name: text

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, argumentnullexception

When I am trying to run the code then I get this error "System.ArgumentNullException: text cannot be null Parameter name: text" it doesn't pull the data from excel file; can anyone please give me the suggestion that how to fix this issue?

here is the script

**ExcelLib.cs**

```
using ExcelDataReader;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Driven
{
    public class ExcelLib
    {
        public static DataTable ExcelToDataTable(string fileName)
        {
            //open file and returns as Stream
            FileStream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            {
                using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                {
                    var result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                    {
                        ConfigureDataTable = (data) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                        {
                            UseHeaderRow = true
                        }
                    });

                    //Get all the Tables
                    DataTableCollection table = result.Tables;
                    //Store it in DataTable
                    DataTable resultTable = table["Sheet1"];

                    //return
                    return resultTable;
                }
            }
        }

            static List<Datacollection> dataCol = new List<Datacollection>();

        public static void PopulateInCollection(string fileName)
        {
            DataTable table = ExcelToDataTable(fileName);

            //Iterate through the rows and columns of the Table
            for (int row = 1; row <= table.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col <= table.Columns.Count; col++)
                {
                    Datacollection dtTable = new Datacollection()
                    {
                        rowNumber = row,
                        colName = table.Columns[col].ColumnName,
                        colValue = table.Rows[row - 1][col].ToString()
                    };
                    //Add all the details for each row
                    dataCol.Add(dtTable);
                }
            }
        }

        public static string ReadData(int rowNumber, string columnName)
        {
            try
            {
                //Retriving Data using LINQ to reduce much of iterations
                string data = (from colData in dataCol
                               where colData.colName == columnName && colData.rowNumber == rowNumber
                               select colData.colValue).SingleOrDefault();

                //var datas = dataCol.Where(x => x.colName == columnName && x.rowNumber == rowNumber).SingleOrDefault().colValue;
                return data.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
        public class Datacollection
        {
            public int rowNumber { get; set; }
            public string colName { get; set; }
            public string colValue { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

**UnitTest1.cs**

```
    using System;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
    using NUnit.Framework;

    namespace Driven
    {

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
        {
            [TestMethod]
            public void TestMethod1()
            {
                ExcelLib.PopulateInCollection(@"D:\Data.xlsx");

                IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("");
                driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).SendKeys(ExcelLib.ReadData(1, "getUserNamefromexcel"));
                driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys(ExcelLib.ReadData(1, "getPasswordfromexcel"));
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("Action")).Click();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Error after Running method UnitTest1**

Message: Test method driven.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: System.ArgumentNullException:text cannot be null parameter name: text

**Error after Debugging method UnitTest1**

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: On which line do you get the exception? can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: @Ahmed thanks for your consideration No i didn't findout any solution up till now 


I get this error in method UnitTest1 and in line # 20 

**line # 20 is** : `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id = 'UserName']")).SendKeys(ExcelLib.ReadData(1, "UserName"));`

please find the attached links

while running I get this error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVqLh.png

while debugging I get this error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqACK.png

Comment: Please reduce your code down to a [mcve] and carefully read that page, especially the last link about "How to debug small programs". It will help you figure out issues like this on your own.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, the `ExcelLib.ReadData()` is returning null. Null is not acceptable for `SendKeys`.

You are returning `null` on exception. That may be one of the reasons.

Check if the data is populated correctly. 
Then check if data is readable or not. Also, print the stack trace of the exception in the read method.